# Help with solar energy math

Tags: physics

At a temperature of 20 degrees, a solar cell has a maximum power of 1000W. If you increase the temperature by 10 degrees and assume that the radiation is the same, what will the maximum effect of the solar cell be?

I'm supposed to use this formulas, but I'm not sure how

[image: Formula]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without further details, it looks like the form of a differential equation for $P_m(T)$ like this:

$\frac{dP_m}{dT}=-0.0045P_m$.  The solution would be an exponential function:

$P_m(T)=A e^{-0.0045T}$.

You can solve for $A$ because you know that at 20 degrees $P_m(20)=1000$.  Then you should be able to solve for other values of $P_m(T)$ as needed.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for this great explanation! I really appreciate your help!